# Axios result returns [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, computed-properties

I am getting feed images from flicker via their API,

I have a computed property `filteredImages`:

```
computed: {
filteredImages: async function() {
  return axios.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&tags=' + this.search + '&nojsoncallback=1')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.data.items;
  })
}
```

},

when I console log the `response.data.items` it returns the correct result set, but when I display it in HTML, it displays `[object Promise]`

Here's the [Pen](https://codepen.io/meekzmik/pen/WNRBaJM)

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Computed props don't support async functions. Moreover they rely on other reactive props to compute them lazily. So you need to call this async function directly every time you need to get filtered images and just put them into some reactive prop in `data` prop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get properties from an HTTP call and render them in DOM

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        search: "",
        filteredImages: "",
    },
    watch: {
        search: function (newVal, oldVal) {
            this.getItems();
        },
    },
    methods: {
        getItems: async function () {
            try {
                const { data } = await axios.get(
                    `https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=jsonp&tags=${this.search}&nojsoncallback=1`
                );

                this.filteredImages = JSON.stringify(data.items)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                this.filteredImages = error.toString();
            }
        },
    },
});
```

However there is an [issue](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/280), flickr works with JSONP and axios or fetch does not support that

You need to use the [JSONP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp) module

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is to put the content of your computed in `mounted` and instead of `return response.data.items` you should fill it in a variable for example like below:

```
data() {
    return {
        items: null,
    }
},
mounted:{
    let vm = this;
    axios.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&tags=' 
    + this.search + '&nojsoncallback=1')
      .then(function (response) {
            vm.items = response.data.items;
      })
 }
```

and in the html u can simply use `items` it will be shown whenever its ready